# mysql prepared statement is not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm new to MySQL. I created a login page that will run PHP to query the database.

I want to make a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection but it is not working. $result gives me 0.

cgi-bin/welcome.php

```
<?php
$email= $_POST["email"];
$pwd = $_POST["password"];

$dbh=mysqli_connect("localhost",
"zzengnin",<password>,"zzengnin_wheel")
or die ('Database is not able to connect');

$qry= "SELECT email FROM Info WHERE email=? AND pw=?";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $qry)) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $pwd);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $result);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    printf("result email  is %s\n", $result);
}


if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    echo "Welcome! '$email', you are officially logged in! ";
}
else{
    echo "Your Email or Password is WRONG!!!!";

    echo $result + " result";
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($dbh);
?>
```

This is the form login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>Wheel Sharing</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Log in</h1>

<form action="cgi-bin/welcome.php" method="post">
Email:  <input name="email" type="text" size="20"/>
<br/>
Password: <input name="password" type="password" >
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

All help appreciated:)

Comment: If you're porting to `mysqli`, which is a good thing, the Object-Oriented interface is usually a lot less messy. That is you use things like `$stmt->bind_param()` instead of the old-school procedural equivalent, a relic from PHP4.

Comment: It's also extremely worrying that you don't appear to have taken any precautions to [properly hash user passwords](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) which exposes your users to considerable risk should your database be compromised.

Comment: You need to capture errors and return them so that you know what happened. What does your error log say happened?

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this code, it's not funny. First you're declaring `$dbh` as DB connection and using `$link` as the query connection parameter. Then there's `echo $result + " result";` I doubt you want to do math here. I can't make heads or tails out of it. All that and not checking for errors anywhere. I don't even know if you're actually using `<password>` as syntax for connection.

Comment: I suggest you read up on [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: You first gotta store your return, then you can bind them. `mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);` Also you can use `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)` to check how many rows you got returned

Comment: @tadman good idea. i will use md5(password) to hash.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I'm new to error-logging since i'm still a newbie to coding. I know my server keeps an error log. Is that enough error logging? Or do you mean I should check each variable in the code to see if it's null?

Comment: @Fred -ii Oops that's a careless mistake. I meant to use $dbh. I'm also new to php so what I was trying to do is print "'$result' result". I'm used to java so did that mistake. mysqli_connect accepts a "password" as parameter...and I'm not going to show my password in public haha. Thanks for catching those newbie mistakes.

Comment: I know that you wouldn't post your actual password, it's just the `<>` around it that I was questioning, whether it part of parameter or not. Plus, the wrong variable of course ;) Problem solved I hope? Oh, and do `echo $result . " result";` instead of `echo $result + " result";` - `+` is JS/Java syntax to concatenate.

Comment: No! **DO NOT** use MD5 for hashing passwords. Follow the advice in the link there and use the password hashing methods in PHP. Even the PHP documentation has a whole [section on proper password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) that you urgently need to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

To this:

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```